# Java - Thread Priorities & Sockets

Tags: java, multithreading

I am developing a web crawler. Each thread of the program try to read 3 hosts / second (330ms Connection & Read Timeout). Each thread's priority is 10 (Ubuntu 12.04).

When i set 10 threads the crawler returns 150 hosts alive (the host didn't timeout).

When i set 400 threads the crawler returns only 20 hosts alive. I don't know how many hosts are really alive or exist.

My question is, is it possible, a thread to not have executed in short period of time, and when it does take its time to continue (from CPU Scheduling) the socket to already timeout? (because thread took too long to process the request).

If this is the case, how many threads do i have to set, so all threads to have equally time?

I am using an ubuntu 12.04 x64 - Desktop, 4GB Ram, CPU i5

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why do you play with thread priorities?

Comment: I want the maximum performance the computer can get. Note: when i don't set priority to threads the result its almost the same (few hosts more are returned).

Comment: of course @fge was just being polite in asking you a question about priorities instead of telling you right away to ***LEAVE THE THREAD PRIORITIES ALONE.***

Comment: 330ms is far too short a timeout. It should be several seconds at least. I doubt that thread scheduling & priority has anything to do with this, in fact you've proved yourself that setting the priorities was just a waste of time. I would start by questioning your design. You should probably be using non-blocking NIO for this, to break the nexus between sockets and threads, and to avoid specifying heroic timeout values.

Comment: All your threads should get as much time as they need, because web-crawling is not CPU intensive. However, they might not get it *when* they need it. Maybe it takes more than 330ms to process all the other threads and get back to the first one.

Comment: What's happening is you're io-bound, you increased the network load 40x, and your response times went up. It's not really a threading issue, here; you just did the classic latency/throughput tradeoff.

Comment: @immibis You was so right. I just thought that cpu was giving enough time to all threads. I was wrong. You can post that as an answer

Comment: Except it's not an answer, it's mostly speculation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It feels like you need an understanding of [Amdahl's Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amdahl%27s_law).  Basically, for N threads, you're going to get [substantially] less than an N-times speedup on your operations.  You only have an i5, which can support anywhere between 2 and 4 parallel tasks at once.  Throwing more threads at it than your system can really handle bogs performance down due to the cost of spinning up threads, switching between threads, and (if you're not using a scheduler or a thread pool) destroying threads.

You wouldn't also be able to guarantee equal execution time, as you depend on external factors such as the opening of the socket to that server, and the server's own connection speed.  There will be servers that are slower than others, which means that the overall time that thread is taking to read from the socket will be slower than others.

I can't say for sure that your performance is tanking due to IO as is speculated, but I would recommend profiling and testing.  Set as many threads on your system as you can handle, and work from there.  Profile your code as best as you can.  Throwing more threads at it would *not* be a good idea.